# using nginx location for having a react app alongside some static pages

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have this Nginx config block

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  mysite.com;
    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    index  index.html;

    location /app {
        root /www;
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location / {
        root /www/landing;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}
```

and I am having a production build of a react application at /www/app and a static Html file in /www/landing. from this configuration, I believe Nginx must redirect all the request that starts with /app (I.E: /app/home/ or /app/markets) to my react application and if the request doesn't start with /app it should try to search in /www/landing folder. This works fine when I enter mysite.com/app, and then if I try to navigate in my site using react-router itself everything works fine due to try_file. However, when I try to directly load (for example) /app/home. Nginx suddenly stops looking in /www/app and tries to load it from /www/landing which breaks everything .
My main concern here is when someone hits the refresh button in the react app.

Comment: The parameters of a `try_files` statement are like URIs, so the last parameter should be `/app/index.html`.

Comment: and add `location /app/ {` trainling slash at the end its important